# Why do I not need the extra lines of code? Ruby Codeacademy

Tags: ruby, private, instance-variables

I'm working on Learn Ruby in Codeacademy (OBJECT-ORIENTED PROGRAMMING II: Private! Keep out!).

Why don't I need to include '(id_name)' after the 'def id' method for the final section?

My attempt is demonstrated in the top code, but the Codeacademy solution tells me that my approach is wrong and the correct approach is much more concise - as shown at the bottom.

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name, breed)
    @name = name
    @breed = breed
  end

  public
  def bark
  puts "Woof!"
  end

  private
  def id (id_number)
  @id_number = id_number
  id_number = 12345
  end
end
```

Correct version

```
  private
  def id
  @id_number = 12345
  end
end
```

Comment: "More concise" nothing. Your approach and the proposed code do completely different things. The former assigns an instance variable to a parameter (and makes a local variable, which it ignores). The latter assigns an instance variable to be equal to a constant.

Comment: What is the role of this value `12345`? As @SilvioMayolo mentioned, the two codes are doing different things. But this constant value `12345` seems a bit odd in this context. It seems to me that what you want to achieve is to have the method `def id(id_number)` and inside the method, assign it to the instance var (`@id_number = id_number`).

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't I need to include '(id_name)' after the 'def id' method for the final section?

I assume you mean `(id_number)` – that's what we call a [method argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Arguments).

Based on the proposed solution:

```
def id
  @id_number = 12345
end
```

... it seems like this method is supposed to set the instance variable `@id_number` to a fixed value of `12345`. In order to do so, you don't need any value from the outside.

However, you *could* pass the value into the method via:

```
def id(value)
  @id_number = value
end
```

But now, you *have to* pass a value when calling the method. Omitting it would result in an `ArgumentError`, which might break existing code.

A third option is to have an argument with a [default value](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Default+Values):

```
def id(value = 12345)
  @id_number = value
end
```

This makes the argument *optional*. If you pass a value, it will be assigned to `@id_number`. Otherwise (i.e. if you call the method without passing an argument) the value `12345` will be used.

Note that `value` is just a name, you could use any other name as well, e.g. `id_number`. Just keep in mind that `id_number` and `@id_number` are different variables. The former being a [local variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variable+Names) and the latter being an [instance variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables).

Regarding your code:

```
def id(id_number)
  @id_number = id_number
  id_number = 12345
end
```

This assigns the passed argument value to `@id_number`. It then assigns `12345` to the local variable `id_number`, thus overwriting its previous value. However, since the variable is never used after the assignment, that line is superfluous. Your code is equivalent to:

```
def id(id_number)
  @id_number = id_number
end
```

This is the same as my 2nd example above. (just with another argument name)